# how to let the image which I draw on a javafx canvas auto scale when I change the canvas size

Tags: javafx

How to make the image on the canvas auto scale when the canvas size is changed

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Canvas canvas;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        canvas.resize(100, 100);
        canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        canvas.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            canvas.widthProperty().setValue(200);
            canvas.heightProperty().setValue(200);
            //I want the rect auto scale but it not work how to make it
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
canvas.scaleXProperty().set(2);
canvas.scaleYProperty().set(2);
```

instead of `canvas.widthProperty().setValue(200); ...`

Comment: I have a StackPane and a canvas on the StackPane I want when the StackPane's size changed the canvas's size change too and the image on the canvas scale to full canvas

Comment: why you don't use javafx.scene.image.ImageView; StackPane is scaleable, too